# Delete all not found i.e. delete all key/values in map not found in set

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

I tried but failed to get the following working with `std::algorithms`:
I have a a `std::map<key_t,value_t> cache` and a `std::set<key_t> selected_items` and I want to delete key/value pairs from `cache`, except for keys contained in `selected_items`.

Here's what I wrote without algorithms:

```
//This could really be written better with std::algorithms but time...
//Delete old
for (auto pair = cache.begin(); pair != cache.end(); ) {
    if (selected_items.find(pair->first) == selected_items.end())
        pair = cache.erase(pair);
    else
        ++pair;
}
```

To make use of the algorithms library, I figured I need to use `std::set_difference` with a compare function and either `std::remove` or `std::map::erase`. But I can't connect the pieces, failed at:

1. What's the correct compare function?
2. Do I have to generate a temporary set with the keys that should be deleted, or can I use the output iterator directly for the remove/erase?

How should my code look?

Comment: Are you sure it works? You are calling `cache.erase()` within the loop. Your iterators are invalidated after the first call to `erase()`.

Comment: I'm sure it works because I'm using it actually, the iterator invalidation is the reason why I assign the return from erase.

Comment: @HappyCoder You're wrong, erase does return a map iterator: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase : "Return value
1-2) Iterator following the last removed element."

Comment: Missed the C++11 tag. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a very interesting question! It turns out that there are several difficulties involved...

- `std::map` uses a `std::pair<const Key, T>` which makes copying/moving of the `std::pairs` impossible (note the `const`)
- no algorithm can perform an actual call to `std::map<>::erase()`because it would invalidate the current iterator
- a standard way to reorder the elements in `cache` (with a e.g simple call to `std::partition`) and then to drop the last elements in `cache` **cannot** work due to point 1

Therefore you have two possibilities:

- Build your own loop that calls `erase` appropriately
- Use `<algorithm>` and a second map that stores the results

Since you are only interested in the second option, we can examine e.g. the use of `std::set_difference()` which indeed does exactly what you want.
**However** since the iterators of the `std::map` and the `std::set` point to different kinds of objects (`std::pair` and `Key`), we have to be careful with our `Comparator`.
A naive approach is simply to supply a function that takes a `const std::pair &` and a `const Key &`. But this **does not work on my machine!** (I do not know if this is a bug... Mac OS X 10.10.5) because `std::set_difference()` decides to sometimes call the `Comparator` with the arguments in reversed order...

Long story short, here is a solution featuring `SFINAE` and `std::set_difference()`:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using Key = int;
using Value = char;

using Pair = std::map<Key,Value>::value_type;

struct Comparator
{
    // Maybe use a custom comparator instead of '<' (see std::set documentation)
    template<class P, class K> auto operator()( const P &p, const K &k ) -> decltype(p.first < k)
    { return (p.first < k); }
    template<class P, class K> auto operator()( const K &k, const P &p ) -> decltype(k < p.first)
    { return (k < p.first); }
};

int main( void )
{
    std::map<Key,Value> cache = { {1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}, {3, 'c'}, {4, 'd'} };
    std::set<Key> selected_items = { 2, 4 };

    std::map<Key,Value> new_cache;
    std::set_difference( cache.begin(), cache.end(),
                        selected_items.begin(), selected_items.end(),
                        std::inserter( new_cache, new_cache.end() ),
                        Comparator() );
    cache = std::move( new_cache ); // Don't use new_cache from here on

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're solution also failed on my machine (had to add `#include <iterator>` though) Win7x64 MSVC++2013 with 

error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type Comparator::operator ()(const P &,const K &)'

Comment: @Superlokkus Yes you are right! That header is needed for `std::inserter()`. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Don't works on MSVC2015 either but works mingw/gcc 4.8.1., so either Microsoft still doesn't fully support C++11 in MSVC 2015 or you're doing only half-legal SFINAE / C++14, although I assume the first.
Either way: Accepted, but still can't use it in my project, yet. Shall I annoy the VC++ guys/gals or do you want to?

Comment: @Superlokkus Unfortunately I don't have access to MSVC so I cannot test it, sry.

Comment: Instead of SFINAE, it would template the comparator with `Key /*, Value*/`

Answer (score 1):

If both your containers use the same sort order on `key_t`, you can just walk both containers and remove element in one container if it is not in the other without having to search for it. O(N) complexity.

Unfortunately, none of the standard algorithms can do removals for you because they work on iterators. To remove using an iterator its container object is required.

Answer (score 1):

Naive attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
    std::set<int> s = {1, 3, 5};
    for (auto it = begin(m); it != end(m); ){
        if (s.count(it->first))
            m.erase(it++);
        else
            ++it;
    }
    for (auto &e : m){
        std::cout << e.first << ' ' << e.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Incorporating @MaximEgorushkin's idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>

void erase_elements_from_map_that_are_not_in_set(
    std::map<int, int> &m, std::set<int> &s){   
    auto sit = begin(s);
    for (auto it = begin(m); it != end(m) && sit != end(s); ){
        while (*sit < it->first){
            ++sit;
            if (sit == end(s))
                return;
        }
        if (*sit == it->first)
            m.erase(it++);
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
    std::set<int> s = {1, 3, 5};
    erase_elements_from_map_that_are_not_in_set(m, s);
    for (auto &e : m){
        std::cout << e.first << ' ' << e.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

You may need to replace `<` in the `while` loop with the common comparison function of the `s` and `m`.

Concerning STL algorithms, you can use `std::find` instead of `count` in the first example, but that is just awkward. I don't know of any other way to use STL algorithms here and I don't think they are needed. You could put the code in your own `erase_elements_from_map_that_are_not_in_set` function if you frequently need it.

Comment: Won't a call to `m.erase()` invalidate the iterator?

Comment: @HappyCoder The iterators pointing to the erased elements become invalid, other iterators don't. That is why `++it` is used which increments the iterator and returns an unincremented intereator. The incremented iterator stays valid and the unincremented iterator is erased, then invalidated and destroyed.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but won't `sit` be incremented to `s.end()` and you will try to deference the off-the-end iterator and then also try to further increment it?!
Also @HappyCoder s question is valid, I think, too.

Comment: @Superlokkus I noticed that too and fixed it.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you. @nwp
Too much of "iterator" usage in your explanation! :P

Comment: I'm sorry @nwp but even after your fix you will still try to deference the off-the-end iterator and also we already have more loops and expressions, than in the solution I try to improve. But I really thank you for the try! :-)

Comment: @Superlokkus Well the first one looks ok. If you don't care if you have `O(n*log(n))` or `O(n)` may as well use the first version.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

```
typedef std::map<int,std::string> cache_t;
typedef std::set<cache_t::key_type> set_t;

void update_cache(cache_t& cache, const set_t& selected_items)
{
    auto test = [selected_items](const cache_t::value_type& x){
        return selected_items.find(x.first) == selected_items.end();
    };
    cache.erase(std::remove_if(cache.begin(), cache.end(), test), cache.end());
}
```

But this isn't possible here, as the error message indicates:

```
32883794.cc:16:64:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:170:8: error: assignment of read-only member ‘std::pair<const int, std::basic_string<char> >::first’
  first = std::forward<first_type>(__p.first);
```

The problem is that we obtain only `iterator` of `pair<const int key_t, value_t>` from the `map`, so can't move its elements.

It should be possible to use `std::copy_if` to create a new instance of `cache` but that likely has substantial memory overhead compared to the approach using a loop.

Comment: This will not work since `std::remove_if()`relies on reordering, but elements in a map cannot be reordered, because the key type is const (see my answer below).

Comment: @Toby Speight Thank you for try, but you code fails with the error (of course I replaced `x.first` with `x->first`):
error C2664: 'bool main::<lambda_69e196b4611491479f9ebafa74e51ea7>::operator ()(std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>) const' : 
cannot convert argument 1 from 
'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' to 
'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>'
Looks like @iolo is right, but nevertheless thanks for the interesting link to the idoim.

Comment: While reading the wikipedia article, I already wondered "How could std::remove reorder the range in a ordered container?" Likely the type problem is intentional.

Comment: @iolo - yes, I posted in a hurry without even compiling, when I was dragged off to a meeting.  Now re-written.